# Cannot get content from HashMap in Java/Bukkit

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

```
public HashMap<Player, Boolean> running = new HashMap<>();

public void load(Player player){
  running.put(player, true);
}

@Eventhandler
public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event){
  if(!running.get(player)) return;
  //More stuff happening here
}
```

I run the "load"-method at the start of my main-class, so the "check"-part cannot happen before "load()" is finished. I use the same player for both methods, but I always get an error:

`Cannot invoke "java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()" because the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null`

I don't know why it's not working, so I'd be very thankful if someone could help me :)

Comment: Class `HashMap` uses the value returned by method `hashCode` of the object that serves as the `HashMap` key, i.e. an instance of class `Player` in your case. So it looks like the `Player` instance that is passed, as a parameter, to method `load` does not have the same "hash code" as the `Player` being referenced in method `onInteract`. You need to debug your code and check whether `player` in method `load` is the same as `player` in method `onInteract`. From your question, it appears that you are assuming that they are the same. You first need to verify that assumption.

Comment: If the return value of method `get` is null, that usually means that the searched for key does not exist in the map.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code for `Player`. It needs to define `hashCode` and `equals`; check the Javadoc on those or do a web search for details. *Effective Java* is also a good resource.

Comment: You don’t need a HashMap.  Just use a HashSet of players:  `private Set<Player> runningPlayers = new HashSet<>();`  (But you still need to make sure the hashCode and equals methods of Player are written correctly and their behavior never changes for a particular instance.)

Comment: Can you share the code that load(Player player) with us also You will want to `getOrDefault` instead of just get in that case `running.getOrDefault(player, false)`
that will make sure there will not be an error but you also need to change it to UUID or make sure to delete the key when `Player` leave or use **weak reference**

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `running.get(player)` to  check if a value exist as it try to get it, but in your case it failed as it's not present.

You have [`containsKey()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-) that will answer. So, you code will be like that:

```
@Eventhandler
public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event){
    if(!running.containsKey(player)) return;
}
```

You can also use method that will automatically manage value as `getOrDefault()` to get value or get default and so be sure there will always have a valid valid. You can also automatically add then with [`computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) that can be used like this:

```
@Eventhandler
public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event){
    if(!running.computeIfAbsent(player, (thisPlayer) -> return shouldItBeTrue(thisPlayer))) return;
}
```